# Execute loop instruction from here DOC

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hi is it possible to execute loop from here DOC in UNIX. I tried myself but it is not working is there any way around for it??

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/global/u70/glob
echo abcd | sudo -S -l
sudo /usr/bin/su - glob  << EOF

for entry in $(ls -r)
  do
  echo "$entry"
  done
EOF
```

Tried with functions as well-:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    path=/global/u70/glob
    echo abcd | sudo -S -l
    sudo /usr/bin/su - glob  << EOF
    run(){
    for entry in $(ls -r)
      do
      echo "$entry"
      done
}
run
    EOF
```

Comment: What is your requirement here? Am sure there are better ways to do it than the one you say.

Comment: @Inian the thing is i have a script kept at my local path which when executed will sudo to different user and there as you see i am taking instruction from here DOC i want a loop to be executed after sudo to another user because if executed outside it then it works for local path not sudo user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a *single quoted* [here document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument):

```
sudo /usr/bin/su - glob  << 'EOF'
[…]
EOF
```

Otherwise shell substitutions such as `$(…)` are executed in the current context and not as the other user. This is similar to how variables and other shell substitutions in single [quoted](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) strings are not expanded.

Comment: can you explain me little more in your terms why we need to use 'EOF'?I mean why it executes in current shell without it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a backslash in front of $(ls -r) for your codes to work.  i.e.

```
sudo /usr/bin/su - glob  << EOF
for entry in \$(ls -r)
  do
  echo "$entry"
  done
EOF
```

This is because when you are inside a here document (between the two EOFs), all variables are local and you have to use these local variables which are separate from the shell variables.  But the confusing part is that if you just put $variable inside heredoc, it would not reference the $variable defined inside the heredoc but from $variable defined in the shell instead.  To access heredoc's own local variable, you have to escape the $, i.e. \$variable.

I am not sure if 'EOF' would work because everything in between 'EOF' and EOF are interpreted as actual characters.